# Multidimensional array issue

Tags: php, arrays

I have created this array from a text file by exploading every line by ';'.

How can i set the value before the '=' sign as key and the other one after the '=' sign as value ?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => title=PHILIPS MIXER H31453
            [1] => gramaj=buc
            [2] => greutate=1
            [3] => prettotal=116.07
            [4] => pretredus=0
            [5] => poza=110.jpg
            [6] => pretunitar=116.07
            [7] => categorie=2210
            [8] => brand=PHILIPS
            [9] => descriere=
            [10] => vizibil=0
            [11] => cod=110
            [12] => ordine=1
            [13] => stoc=0
            [14] => nou=0
            [15] => cant_variabila=0
            [16] => congelat=0
            [17] => tva=24
            [18] => alias=philips-mixer-h31453
        )
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => titlu=PHILIPS MIXER H31453
            [1] => gramaj=buc
            [2] => greutate=1
            [3] => prettotal=116.07
            [4] => pretredus=0
            [5] => poza=110.jpg
            [6] => pretunitar=116.07
            [7] => categorie=2210
            [8] => brand=PHILIPS
            [9] => descriere=
            [10] => vizibil=0
            [11] => cod=110
            [12] => ordine=1
            [13] => stoc=0
            [14] => nou=0
            [15] => cant_variabila=0
            [16] => congelat=0
            [17] => tva=24
            [18] => alias=philips-mixer-h31453
        )
)
```

The result should be like :

```
            [titlu] => PHILIPS MIXER H31453
            [gramaj] => buc
            [greutate] => 1
            [prettotal] => 116.07
```

and so on...

This is where i need it.

```
function runSql(){
    session_start();
    header('Content-type: text/html;charset=utf8');
    global $outcount;

    $db = $this->pdoconnect();
    $db->setErrorLog(true);

    $files = $_SESSION['sql'];
    $to_process = array_shift($files);
    $get_sql = @file_get_contents($to_process);
    @unlink($to_process);

    $split = explode(";", $get_sql);
    unset($split[count($split) - 1]); // Clear the last empty element


    $final_array = array();

    foreach ($split as $row) {
             $final_array[] = explode(',', $row); // Explode each row by , to each row of final_array
            }


    //$stmt = $db->insertBatch('produse', $final_array, true)->getAllLastInsertId();


            echo 1;
         }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do the same thing, explode each item and use the first part as the key and second part as the value

```
$split       = explode(";", $get_sql);
$final_array = array();

foreach ($split as $row) {
    $arr = explode(',', $row);
    $res = array();

    foreach($arr as $item) {
        $parts = explode("=", $item);
        $res[$parts[0]] = $parts[1];
    }

    $final_array[] = $res;
}
```

Comment: It works just for the firs array, updated my question

Comment: That's because all the arrays have the same key, so when you do `$arr["title"]` in the loop it probably overwrites the value. Try the updated code